# Vertical aligning of two different sized text elements

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have two different elements, a logo and navigation. The logo is 48px but the navigation is 16px. The challenge I am facing is vertically aligning them both and then horizontally aligning them with my webpage content.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li>ABOUT</li>
        <li>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        CONTENT  
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in my CSS:

```
.header {
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;

    display: table;
}

.logo {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    display: table;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100%;

    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This code produces an output where both are vertically aligned but I'm not sure how to then align it with the content in the container, since the `margin` on the container is `auto`. If someone could give me some direction that would be great.

My overall goal is to align both the logo and the navigation vertically within the header but then say for example my content is 590px wide, align the logo (horizontally) to the left of that and the navigation to the right.

The output should look like

```
|logo|        |nav |
|contentttttttttttt|
```

Thanks

Comment: Align both in the middle vertically and horizontally?

Comment: @imbondbaby I want to align both vertically, but then say my content is width 590px, align the logo on the left hand side of content and the nav on right hand side. Like at the top of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tqBUb/

The following code perfectly centers your different sized text vertically, and the total combined width of those two elements horizontally. Is this what you want? Either way this is probably a good starting point for you. The width of the header element can be changed to anything and it adjusts accordingly.

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <span>LOGO</span>
        </div>
        <nav class="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li>HOME</li>
                <li>ABOUT</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    color: #fff;
    width: 80%;
    background: blue;
}

.container {
    display: table;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo span {
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 1;
}

.main-nav {
    display: table-cell;
}

.main-nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.main-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

```
|logo|_______|nav|
|_____content____|
```

To achieve this format at 590px, you will need a media query breakpoint for screens widths of 590 or less. Then... just change the display: table; on .container to display: block; and the display: table-cell; div's to display: block. Then Flow the .logo div left, and float .main-nav right.

Comment: Excellent! One more question - if my body content is say 590px wide and I set `.container` to `width: 590px` the logo and nav don't line up either side of the content in the body. How is this achieved?

Comment: @Shazer2 - Please see my edit to the answer above at the very bottom I have asked a question pertaining to the format you want at 590px;

Comment: please refer to the OP for my desired output.

Comment: @Shazer2 I understand you want the logo and nav left and right but I don't understand their vertical relation.  Note the bottom of my answer two very different interpretations of what you want.  One is easy to achieve, the other nearly impossible.

Comment: sorry, OP is now updated with how I want it. So the left hand side of the logo aligns with left hand side of body content and right hand side of nav aligns with right hand side of body content.